# unable to check for popup in windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using VsCode in Windows 11. I want a Python program that plays an error sound whenever a notification popup comes at the lower right part of my screen. The coordinates are x = 1828 and y = 952. I have an error. wav file, and the Python program is saved in the same folder where the wav file is.

I've tried using the Winsound module, but it only helped to get the sound.

Comment: What is your question?